# List to data frame in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to grab transaction data from plaid and input it into a data frame with clean columns. The "before" format is a list as excerpted below.

My goal is that the "after" format is a data frame where there is a column for each name in the list (e.g., "account_id" or "amount") such that I can then parse the list and insert values in each column.

I'm new to python--I'm fluent in r/dplyr but the syntax is confusing me.

Thanks in advance!

```
{'account_id': 'nKllGzvJQeIpZwvxlv1Mhw98Zdo57Ec6ZNEm5',
 'account_owner': None,
 'amount': 4.33,
 'authorized_date': datetime.date(2020, 12, 8),
 'authorized_datetime': None,
 'category': ['Food and Drink', 'Restaurants', 'Coffee Shop'],
 'category_id': '13005043',
 'check_number': None,
 'date': datetime.date(2020, 12, 8),
 'datetime': None,
 'iso_currency_code': 'USD',
 'location': {'address': None,
              'city': None,
              'country': None,
              'lat': None,
              'lon': None,
              'postal_code': None,
              'region': None,
              'store_number': None},
 'merchant_name': 'Starbucks',
 'name': 'Starbucks',
 'payment_channel': 'in store',
 'payment_meta': {'by_order_of': None,
                  'payee': None,
                  'payer': None,
                  'payment_method': None,
                  'payment_processor': None,
                  'ppd_id': None,
                  'reason': None,
                  'reference_number': None},
 'pending': False,
 'pending_transaction_id': None,
 'personal_finance_category': None,
 'transaction_code': None,
 'transaction_id': 'llvvGK61QjH1eX8yP8qZC8BxB3WegMFZrXRjr',
 'transaction_type': 'place',
 'unofficial_currency_code': None}
```

enter code here

Comment: BTW, a "list" in Python is different from  a "list" in R. In R, a list is collection of key-value pairs. In Python, a list is an ordered collection of elements. A list in R is more like a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) in Python. What you posted is a dictionary, not a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, I would use the [DataFrame constructor](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html), in the list-of-records format.

Example:

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd

transaction = {'account_id': 'nKllGzvJQeIpZwvxlv1Mhw98Zdo57Ec6ZNEm5',
 'account_owner': None,
 'amount': 4.33,
 'authorized_date': datetime.date(2020, 12, 8),
 'authorized_datetime': None,
 'category': ['Food and Drink', 'Restaurants', 'Coffee Shop'],
 'category_id': '13005043',
 'check_number': None,
 'date': datetime.date(2020, 12, 8),
 'datetime': None,
 'iso_currency_code': 'USD',
 'location': {'address': None,
              'city': None,
              'country': None,
              'lat': None,
              'lon': None,
              'postal_code': None,
              'region': None,
              'store_number': None},
 'merchant_name': 'Starbucks',
 'name': 'Starbucks',
 'payment_channel': 'in store',
 'payment_meta': {'by_order_of': None,
                  'payee': None,
                  'payer': None,
                  'payment_method': None,
                  'payment_processor': None,
                  'ppd_id': None,
                  'reason': None,
                  'reference_number': None},
 'pending': False,
 'pending_transaction_id': None,
 'personal_finance_category': None,
 'transaction_code': None,
 'transaction_id': 'llvvGK61QjH1eX8yP8qZC8BxB3WegMFZrXRjr',
 'transaction_type': 'place',
 'unofficial_currency_code': None}

transactions = [transaction]

df = pd.DataFrame(transactions)
```

Note that some columns are themselves objects, like the payment category column or payment_meta column. You didn't specify if you thought those should be handled specially or broken out into multiple columns, but it's something you should consider doing.

Also note that `transactions` is a list, and you can put multiple transactions in the same format into it, and construct the dataframe all at once. (This is preferable to creating multiple dataframes and appending them together, for the same reason as in dplyr.)

Comment: Thanks! df in your code is not as expected. It has 1 row and 100 columns. the correct output. I *think* that this has two issues. 1) it is transposed(should be 100 rows based on the data I used, and 2) the current 1 row has what I want to be columns embedded in the data. Will send screenshot shortly.

Comment: @rayfinkle 1) Have you tried [DataFrame.transpose()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html) to transpose the dataframe? 2) I know, it's mentioned above. You didn't specify how you wanted nesting to be handled, so I left it as-is. Plausibly you might want normalization, breaking up each dictionary into multiple columns, or something else.

Comment: worked. thanks so much!!